# Changing the user name

Tags: support

Last evening, I got cooked up by the behaviour of site users, expecially, voting down an answer for no particular reason. I had decided to go ahead with deleting my user profile from the network.

Later, the members of the community who are also regular users of the Math Chat Room talked me into staying. Considering some relevant issues, I have chosen to stay and I sincerely hope  I won't regret it.

Now, I'd like to change my username which the system would not let me do. Can some moderator help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've changed your user name back.

Comment: Thank You so much.